# Checking for invitation on caller's machine

Tags: chat

I never used talk command appeared in 4.2BSD.

the command I am using:

```
talk username
```

and received:

```
[Checking for invitation on caller's machine]
```

lately found:

```
No talk daemon on myserver
```

although:

```
#:BSD: Shell, login, exec and talk are BSD protocols.
talk        dgram   udp wait    nobody.tty  /usr/sbin/in.talkd  in.talkd
```

what should be the next step?

Ubuntu version: 18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver).

Comment: By talk - do you mean [gnu talk](http://gnutalk.sourceforge.net)?

Comment: No. The talk command appeared in 4.2BSD